# How can I set up a ProgressBar with a specific step in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar, android-handler

I want the time to increase progress regularly and apply every time the variable value is 50.
I mean, every **step** of the increase can be controlled with a certain amount

How do I do this by a Handler on Android?

#### Example

```
if ( progress == 50 && progress == 100 && progress == 150 ... ) 
     do setProgress
```

In the example above, **every step is 50**

**My code is here and use my custom progress in Handler :**

```
private Handler mIncomingHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (REQUEST_TIMER == 0) {
            if (msg.what == 0) {
                if (progress < 100) {
                    progress++;
                    progress_bar.setProgress(progress);
                    if (progress == 99)
                        CustomActivity.this.finish();
                }
            }
        } else if (msg.what == 0) {
            if (progress < 100) {
                progress++;
                progress_bar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: your code looks correct, but I don't see you are doing omething for your handler to call `handleMessage`

Comment: This code is a _summary_ of the whole project and is relevant to my question
So I deleted the extra code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is your requirement,Hope this may help you

In my case i am updating a progress bar based on audio file position playing in a media player 'mp' so i used the following code.

```
 progress_bar.setMax(100);
 if(mp.getDuration()!=0) {
     progress_bar.setProgress(100 * mp.getCurrentPosition() / mp.getDuration());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below method for progress bar animation.

```
private void setProgressDialogAnimation(ProgressBar mProgressBar, int process) {
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mProgressBar, "progress", 0, process);
    animation.setDuration(1500);
    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.start();
}
```

pass progressbar object and process in this method.